# How do you use grep to find terms that are n characters long?

Tags: grep, regex

I'm using grep to filter the Mac OS X dictionary words file (by default located at /usr/share/dict/words).

I want to use grep to retrieve all words four characters long. How do I do this?

My best guess for how to do this was:

```
grep [:alpha:]{4} words
```

But that returns zero results.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Trying to remember how much of regex language `grep` supports... does

```
grep '^....$' words
```

work for you? Note that since you are searching a dictionary file, I'm not sure you need to restrict yourself to letters.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster what about them? We're searching a dictionary file here so I wouldn't expect there to be any. If you have your own, different, question, you can [ask it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 27):

It should be:

```
grep -E '^[[:alpha:]]{4}$' words
```

We anchor it (since a 5-letter string also contains a 4-letter string), and POSIX character classes must be contained in a bracket expression (`[]`).  Also, we quote for the shell.  And it needs to be extended, so -E.

Comment: +1. Good stuff. Same without -E:  `grep '^[[:alpha:]]\{4\}$' words`

Comment: Your modified answer works, but Aakash's solution is slightly more succinct so I'm giving the accept to him. Thanks for your help. Upvotes all round.

Comment: @Brain, yes, it's more succinct, but it does something different. `[:alpha:]` matches letters, `.` matches any character except NUL.

Answer (score 0):

grep uses [BRE](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-syntax.html)

What you specfically wanted is

```
grep "[:alpha:]\{4\}" words
```